# SQL Query doesn't execute

Tags: php, mysql, string, null, prepared-statement

I've got the following PHP code:

```
$statement_geo = $GLOBALS['conn']->prepare($GLOBALS['istatement_insert_geo']);
$statement_geo->bind_param("isddssssiiiiiisisiiiii", $statement_geo_plz, $statement_geo_ort, $statement_geo_breitengrad, $statement_geo_laengengrad, $statement_geo_strasse, $statement_geo_hnr, $statement_geo_bundesland, $statement_geo_land, $statement_geo_etage, $statement_geo_anzahl_etagen, $statement_geo_lage_im_bau_links, $statement_geo_lage_im_bau_rechts, $statement_geo_lage_im_bau_vorne, $statement_geo_lage_im_bau_hinten, $statement_geo_wohnungsnr, $statement_geo_gl_id, $statement_geo_regionaler_zusatz, $statement_geo_karten_makro, $statement_geo_karten_mikro, $statement_geo_virtuelletour, $statement_geo_luftbilder, $statement_geo_adressveroeffentlichung);
```

I have the following code, which works fine:

```
$statement_geo_plz = $plz;
$statement_geo_ort = $ort;
$statement_geo_breitengrad = NULL;
$statement_geo_laengengrad = NULL;
$statement_geo_strasse = $strasse;
$statement_geo_hnr = $hausnr;
$statement_geo_bundesland = NULL;
$statement_geo_land = NULL;
$statement_geo_etage = $etage;
$statement_geo_anzahl_etagen = $anzahletagen;
$statement_geo_lage_im_bau_links = NULL;
$statement_geo_lage_im_bau_rechts = NULL;
$statement_geo_lage_im_bau_vorne = NULL;
$statement_geo_lage_im_bau_hinten = NULL;
$statement_geo_wohnungsnr = NULL;
$statement_geo_gl_id = NULL;
$statement_geo_regionaler_zusatz = NULL;
$statement_geo_karten_makro = NULL;
$statement_geo_karten_mikro = NULL;
$statement_geo_virtuelletour = NULL;
$statement_geo_luftbilder = NULL;
$statement_geo_adressveroeffentlichung = 0;

$statement_geo->execute();
$statement_geo_last_id = $GLOBALS['conn']->insert_id;
```

When I try to add a value to "$statement_geo_land" or "$statement_geo_bundesland", like:

```
$statement_geo_plz = $plz;
$statement_geo_ort = $ort;
$statement_geo_breitengrad = NULL;
$statement_geo_laengengrad = NULL;
$statement_geo_strasse = $strasse;
$statement_geo_hnr = $hausnr;
$statement_geo_bundesland = NULL;
$statement_geo_land = "AUT";
$statement_geo_etage = $etage;
$statement_geo_anzahl_etagen = $anzahletagen;
$statement_geo_lage_im_bau_links = NULL;
$statement_geo_lage_im_bau_rechts = NULL;
$statement_geo_lage_im_bau_vorne = NULL;
$statement_geo_lage_im_bau_hinten = NULL;
$statement_geo_wohnungsnr = NULL;
$statement_geo_gl_id = NULL;
$statement_geo_regionaler_zusatz = NULL;
$statement_geo_karten_makro = NULL;
$statement_geo_karten_mikro = NULL;
$statement_geo_virtuelletour = NULL;
$statement_geo_luftbilder = NULL;
$statement_geo_adressveroeffentlichung = 0;

$statement_geo->execute();
$statement_geo_last_id = $GLOBALS['conn']->insert_id;
```

...the query will be not executed. The log file says the statement gets prepared but there is no execution. The above one, does.

Any ideas? I'm awake since 5 hours solving this problem and I have no idea...I'm helpless...

If you need the table, for testing etc. : http://pastebin.com/nfGrH30i

Comment: Have you tied without quotation marks ? like so :  $statement_geo_land = 'AUT';

Comment: Have you tried displaying any errors?
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.error.php

Comment: yeah i've tried with '' after printing the error message, which says "MySQL Server has gone away" nothing works anymore.....

Comment: What is the actual query? An insert?

Comment: yes!, the code above!

Comment: Try increasing the size of `g_land` in the db. You have given a size of 3, and your input "AUT" looks fine, but , who knows...

Comment: after increasing and restarting my whole computer (only xampp didn't work), evrything works fine